# Trouble installing Adafruit's DHT11 Python library

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, libraries, adafruit

I followed these instructions to install the Adafruit DHT11 library (https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_DHT):

```
git clone https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_DHT.git
cd Adafruit_Python_DHT
sudo apt-get install build-essential python-dev
sudo python setup.py install
```

And I found the library installed under /home/pi (I'm working with a **Raspberry Pi 3**). The file I want to fun is in /home/pi/Desktop so I move the library into that directory. However, I still can't run my python file properly. This is the error I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
   File "sensorRead.py", line 4, in <module>
      import Adafruit_DHT
ImportError: No module named 'Adafruit_DHT'
```

How do I get rid of this error? And where should I move my file (or the library) so the library will work? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. I moved my file into `Adafruit_Python_DHT/examples` and ran it with the `python sensorRead.py` command. To be honest, I don't know why it works when I put it into examples, but it does.